# Graph where the nodes are stacked/have multiple levels?

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if there is a name for this type of graph, or a more general term for this concept:

Imagine a directed graph where each node has multiple levels, for example: A[1] -> B[1] -> C[1] -> A[2]

When reasoning about the graph, you can ask if there is an edge from C -> A, which in this case is true because layer 1 of node C is connected to layer 2 of node A.

You can also be more specific: is there an edge from C -> A exclusively in layer 1? No, because the edge crosses through both levels 1 and 2. The same can be said for layer 2. There is however an edge from B -> C in layer 1.

The reason for this approach is that with the problem I am trying to model, sometimes all you care about is if there is a connection at any level, and sometimes the level is important.